# Migrate database problem in laravel 5.7.16

Tags: laravel

I am new in Laravel. I am facing a problem to migrate my users and password reset table.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is
>   767 bytes (SQL: a lter table users add unique
>   users_email_unique(email))

I have tried so many solution like (AppServiceProvider, database collation change, changing migration file ) but none of them give me a solution.

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
}
```

**Database.php**

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Comment: What is your problem ? does it showing errors ? upload your error here.

Comment: Type your error please

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
 violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: a
lter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))

Comment: When I give the command user table add with my database but collation shows utf8mb4_unicode_ci but I changed my database.php

Comment: Show your migration table for user and password reset.

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }

Answer (score 0):

After setting defaultStringLength in AppServiceProvider maybe re-run your project with php artisan serve solve your problem.